# Open webform from GridView to add record to SQL table. C#

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm not sure how to go about this. I am able to pass the Primary key value from the selected row in a GridView to the next page using Response.Redirect, but I need to populate a couple other fields from that row too. Here is what I have. I want to know if I can set another textbox equal to a value using the primary key value, that was passed from the previous page.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dataKey = Request.QueryString["id"];

        ProjNo.Text = dataKey;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not altogether clear what you are trying to to do but i can make some observations.  Once you are on the new Webform all the context from the original request has gone unless you have saved it somewhere at the time of the Response.Redirect().  You have a few options, putting it into the querystring:

Response.Redirect("/page.aspx?id=" + id + "&field1=" + field1);

You could just save it in the session:

HttpContext.Current.Session["field1"] = field1;

Comment: This is helpful. I want to pass it in the querystring. It is coming from a GridView though, not another textbox. I guess really what I need to ask is how to specify a row from a GridView into a string?